# Security review for free apps in appexchange

Tags: appexchange, security-review

We have created one app and planning to list in appexchange as free app. Do we need to pass security review, if yes then is it free or paid?. We have partner developer org to list in Appexchange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you do have to submit your application for security review; all apps must be vetted to ensure they're not a potential risk to customers' data.

For free apps the review is free, currently it's $2700 for paid applications.

Comment: How can know when to list the app after security review? is there any status like security passed or rejected?

Comment: Exactly that, Salesforce.com will email you when the app has passed the review. The process can take 2-3 months even if there are no security concerns.

Comment: As i heard from some one said that we can use checkmarx for security review and the response is very fast. So is Checkmarx is free for free apps or we have to pay for for free apps also?

Comment: The Checkmarx Eclipse plug-in isn't sold by Salesforce. There is a free trial last I checked, and it's very much worth it. Alternatively you can run the web-based checkmarx but the reporting isn't as specific and you can only run so many checks per day I believe.

Comment: Not sure about the cost of Checkmarx, but even after doing that you'll still need to submit to Salesforce. Checkmarx would be a good way of ensuring you don't have any major issues before hand though (you're supposed to run the web one at least as part of the process).

Comment: I just completed a review for a free app - it was actually pretty quick (2 weeks I think). But if you want to list it on appexchange, you have to go through the review